# Redirect output of current script to a socket

Tags: debugging, nc

I am trying to debug a shell script executing on a remote server, where I do not have access to the standard output of the script. Can I redirect the output to go over a socket?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to achieve this by redirecting output to a fifo, and using the fifo as the input for `nc`:

```bash
#/bin/sh -e

# create a fifo
unlink /tmp/f
mkfifo /tmp/f

# connect to the server in the background
nc localhost 4444 < /tmp/f &

# redirect stdout to the fifo
exec > /tmp/f

# an example that writes to stdout
while true; do
    sleep 1
    echo "hello world"
done
```

Note this is only transmitting stdout to the socket; you could add `exec 2> /tmp/f` to include stderr. I didn't succeed at getting stdin wired up but it should be possible.

(An earlier version of this script swapped `nc` with `exec`; this worked on Zsh, but not BusyBox's shell, ash.)

Comment: wouldn't just piping the command in question to `nc` do? i.e. `while ...; done | nc ...`. Or put the actual work in a function and redirect that, `dosmth() { while ...; done ; }` and `dosmth | nc ...`

Comment: Note that `[ 1 ]` doesn't test the numerical value you put there but only checks if the string inside the brackets is non-empty. I.e. `[ 0 ]` and `[ false ]` are as true as `[ 1 ]` (but `[ "" ]` would be falsy). For an always-true condition, you could use `while true; do...`

Comment: Ok, switched to `while true`. My scenario involved an init script that I could modify, but I could not control how it was executed by the kernel.